# How to implement SignalR in ASP.NET web API project with Angular 6 front end

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, angular6

I already created a ASP.NET web API project and separately created Angular 6 project and connected 2 domains with CORS. Now I just want to add SignalR to get user notifications in the database update of a certain table.

EX: when I add a new user to the system existing users need to notify a new user added in real time.

I created another ASP.NET web API project in the same solution in Visual Studio to implement SignalR and I have no idea to connect those projects.

How to implement SignalR functionalities to get real time notifications. Please give some explanation with code snippets.

Comment: Take a look at proxy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#proxy